# Why would Java skip lines of code after method failure?

Tags: java

I've seen this behavior a few times lately.  In the code below, why would execution jump to the finally block immediately after executing method2?   I know method2 failed in some way, but I do know that neither method3 nor method4 are executed, instead jumping to method 5 in the finally block

```
try {
  method1();
  method2();  // fails
  method3();  // not executed

} catch(Exception e) {
  method4();  // not executed

} finally {
  method5();
}
```

Comment: How does method2 fail?  How do you know method4 isn't being run?

Comment: At a guess? `method2()` throws a `Throwable` (or `RuntimeException`) which is not a sub-class of `Exception` and is therefor not caught by the `Exception` block (the `finally` block is entered before the throwable propagates up the call stack).

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you're clear on why `method3()` is not executing.

A possible reason that `method4()` would not execute is that `method` is throwing a `Throwable` that is not a subclass of `Exception` - most likely some kind of `Error`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the exception being thrown is not being caught by the type "Exception"
For example, an out of memory error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        method1();
        method2();  // fails
        method3();  // not executed

    } catch(Exception e) {
        method4();  // not executed

    } finally {
        method5();
    }
}

private static void method5() {
    System.out.println("Done");
}

private static void method4() {
    System.out.println("Hit");
}

private static void method3() {

}

private static void method2() {
    throw new OutOfMemoryError();
}

private static void method1() {
}
```

You can catch error types by `try {} catch (Throwable t) { }`